# ViewPager and TabLayout идейный вопрос

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Почти все статьи в интернете говорят делать для `viewPager` адаптер наследуемый от `FragmentViewPagerAdapter` и затем кидать туда фрагменты, соединять с `TabLayout` и все хорошо. А почему бы не делать обычный `PagerAdapter` и затем просто кидать в него `view`. Почему обычно делают через фрагменты? Есть ли у этого какие-то реальные преимущества или это просто так исторически сложилось?

Comment: Fragment позволяет осуществлять взаимодействие с пользователем (реагировать на нажатия, выполнять код), View - нет, только внешний вид (точнее сделать можно через активити, но это будет плохое решение). Асоответственно, если ваши страницы не должны быть интерактивными, то можете использовать View, иначе Fragment

Comment: @pavlofff А если у меня есть такой viewPager с view. А вся логика view обрабатывается в классе откуда я получаю view. Чем плох такой способ?

Comment: мне не удается вполне осилить ваш способ по строчке "вся логика view обрабатывается в классе откуда я получаю view" из за крайне малого количества информации по реализации, поэтому ничего о преимуществах или недостатках сказать я не могу.

Comment: @pavlofff Например есть активность A. В ней есть view pager. Этот viewPager я заполняю view через PagerAdapter. Теперь у меня есть еще один класс B. В классе B я создаю view и, например, даю ей OnClickListener с каким-то действием. И затем возвращаю как View. Таким образом я из класса B верну view, положу в List класса A и дам viewPager класса A. Хорошо ли так делать? Если нет, то почему?

Comment: манипуляции с View между классами череваты утечками памяти и вообще View это не данные, а представления они не объект для перемещений. Так делать не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Использование `FragmentViewPagerAdapter` необходимо, чаще всего, когда внутри каждого слайда нужна своя логика работы с ним. Логичнее всего в этом случае записать логику работы внутри `fragment`, а не в родительский `activity` / `fragment` (дабы не плодить непонятный г**нокод).

В свою очередь, `PagerAdapter` чаще всего используется, когда логика работы с конкретным элементом не нужна и может быть описана для всех слайдов разом.